# Automatic download from Sourceforge during installation

Tags: java, download, sourceforge

I have a Java project which uses platform specific libraries. They are quite large but I can figure out which ones I need in an installer and download them. I'd like to download them from Sourceforge (where the rest of my project lives).

Is there a way to do automatic downloads from SF?

How do I make sure the download use the best mirror?

Comment: As an alternative you could use public maven repositories

Comment: Yes, but I'm using Eclipse artifacts and they are still arguing how to name them. Plus I'm using milestone artifacts which have additional issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you append `?use_mirror=autoselect` to the path of your download (beginning with **http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/**), SourceForge will send a 302 Found response to redirect you to your closest mirror.  For example:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/getgnuwin32/getgnuwin32/0.6.30/GetGnuWin32-0.6.3.exe?use_mirror=autoselect

Redirects to the following location for me:

http://superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/getgnuwin32/getgnuwin32/0.6.30/GetGnuWin32-0.6.3.exe

In terms of downloading the latest version, you can parse the RSS feed for the project's files.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Currently you need to do this: `?ts=$TIMESTAMP&use_mirror=autoselect`, where $TIMESTAMP is the seconds since the 1970 (i.e. the UNIX epoch), and presumably must be somewhat recent. I find using the current timestamp works.

Comment: On a UNIX-like system, $(date +%s) generates such a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab a download page (like http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpptest/files/cpptest/cpptest-1.1.0/cpptest-1.1.0.zip/download) and scan for `Please use this <a href="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/.../...?use_mirror=..." class="direct-download">direct link</a>` with a regular expression. Then you have soure forge pick a mirror for you.